# PHP search with few parameters

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have an query that I am trying to do search with multiple parameters to sort my data response from sql.

The query code :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `apartments` WHERE `building_num`='{$i}' ORDER by `apartment_num` ASC";
```

The search form :

```html
<form method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="price">
    <select class="styled-select2" name="type">
        <option value="0">Apartment type</option>
        <option value="דופלקס">Duplex</option>
        <option value="דירה">Apartments</option>
        <option value="דירת גן">דירת גן</option>
    </select>
    <select class="styled-select2" name="rooms">
        <option value="0">rooms</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    <select class="styled-select2" name="price">
        <option value="0">Price</option>
        <option value="700000-800000">700,000-800,000 ₪ </option>
        <option value="800000-900000">800,000-900,000 ₪</option>
        <option value="900000-1000000">900,000-1,000,000 ₪</option>
        <option value="1000000-1100000">1,000,000-1,100,000 ₪</option>
        <option value="1100000-1200000">1,100,000-1,200,000 ₪</option>
        <option value="1200000-1300000">1,200,000-1,300,000 ₪</option>
        <option value="1300000-1400000">1,300,000-1,400,000 ₪</option>
        <option value="1400000">1,400,000 up</option>
    </select>

    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="search">
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

There are three parameters but they are not required, could the customer only use 'apartment type' AND 'Price' OR only one parameter, I tried for few hours to write query with no success, Any one can help ?

```
// Vars on table apartments
// Rooms - > Rooms
// Price -> price
// Apartment type -> type
```

Comment: add the city name petah tikva and no one would want to search... ;)

Comment: Please provide the table structure and some sample data

Comment: Try searching for mysql's LIKE operator. Query hint: ...this LIKE '%that%'  When having difficulties with your new query, I'm glad to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

1st of all, there's no direct link between and query (or queries) and tge options you're giving to the customer...

If you **want to** then you can allow the customer to fill some of the fields and if you don't then no... it's a matter of decision, from which derives the development

There's missing example code, so I can obly answer regarding the query and add some remarks

Since you've given specific select options, then you should use it for specific searches 
I would also use some validations on the $_POST information returned

Regarding the query, I need to assume that all of the options are saved in the apartments table, under that, then the query  should be something like this :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `apartments` WHERE
rooms = $rooms
OR `type` = $type
OR (price BETWEEN  *$range_min* AND *$range_max*) 
ORDER by `apartment_num` ASC";
```

If you want all parameters combined you should use AND instead of OR
and, again, you can decide you want both and use different queries for each scenario the user givea

Comment: what are the asterisks supposed to represent?

Comment: I tried to make the variables italic, because, as I wrote in my answer, they need to be handled before bwing put in the query. I'll remove them

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have to build dynamic query as below :-

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `apartments` WHERE ";
$condition = "";
$condition .= ($rooms=='')?"":" or 'rooms'= $rooms ";
$condition .= ($type=='')?"":" or 'type'= $type ";
$condition .= ($price=='')?"":" or prince bewteen 'range_min' AND 'range_max'"; 

$sql .= $condition;
$sql .= " ORDER by `apartment_num` ASC";
```

In this way you can make all three filters free to select or not.